# facebook sdk access token session expires too early

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

The reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

states:

> By default most Access Tokens have a finite validity period that is generally around 1 to 2 hours long. In order to continue using these tokens after the expire time, they need to be extended.

So why in all the example given in the facebook php sdk the login expires only after a few minutes and after that a new login is required?

thanks

*EDIT*

This is one example's code (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php)

```
    <?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '344617158898614',
  'secret' => '6dc8ac871858b34798bc2488200e503d',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the code that you're using to retrieve the access token?

Comment: just updated the question with a snippet ;)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too recently. I think it has something to do with the `/me` so I tried changing it to `/user_id`. Here is the code I used:

```
require_once 'facebook-php/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '13********',
  'secret' => '7a***********',
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '13**********', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>   <?
if ($userId) { 
    $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId); 
?>
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $userId; ?>/picture" align="left" width="24px" height="24px" style="padding: 2px 10px 2px 5px"> <div style="margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; display:inline; height:24px; line-height:28px"><b>Hi there, <?php echo $userInfo['name']; ?>!</b></div>
<? } else { ?>
  <div class="fb-login-button" style="display:inline; position:relative; top:3px" scope="email,user_birthday,publish_stream,offline_access"></div>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

That code works prefect for me and as long as they are signed into Facebook they come up on the site.

Comment: Also, be sure to update to the latest facebook-php-sdk, there was a bug in it a few months ago that was causing that problem too.

Comment: i can't get the point. if y call the /user_id instead of /me you will obtain a longer token? that's weird!
Anyway, i see you are also using the event auth.login, so you may be interested in this bug I reported: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/524245490930206

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why using user_id instead of me works, but it has fixed my issues with long lived sessions. Also, looking at your bug, I was using it on the site when they authorize my app, not necessarily when they log into Facebook. Using it like that, I never had any issues with it.